Dot Net packages to work with resources inside Azure Kubernetes service
I am working on .Net tool to check statuses of resources inside Azure Kubernetes service (nodes in Node pool, pods etc.).
But I do not know, how to get that internal resources like nodes etc.
I am using the following package for .Net to work with Azure Kubernetes service - Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerService. But I can dive to Node Pools only - ContainerServiceAgentPoolResource:
//...
var managedClusters = resourceGroup.GetContainerServiceManagedClusters();

foreach (var managedCluster in managedClusters)
{
        var nodePools = managedCluster.GetContainerServiceAgentPools();
        foreach (var nodePool in nodePools)
        {
            var poolName = nodePool.Data.Name;

            var poolProvisioningState = nodePool.Data.ProvisioningState;
                
            //how to get Nodes etc. from nodePool (ContainerServiceAgentPoolResource)
        }

}

How to get Nodes etc. from ContainerServiceAgentPoolResource? I did not find any methods in Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerService package; also I did not find any packages that can help me with this.


You could try something like this:
dotnet add package KubernetesClient

// Path to your kubeconfig file
string kubeConfigPath = "<path-to-your-kubeconfig-file>";

// Load the kubeconfig file
var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile(kubeConfigPath);
IKubernetes kubernetesClient = new Kubernetes(config);

// Get the list of nodes
var nodes = kubernetesClient.ListNode();
Console.WriteLine("\nNodes:");
foreach (var node in nodes.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"- {node.Metadata.Name}");
}

// Get the list of pods in all namespaces
var pods = kubernetesClient.ListPodForAllNamespaces();
Console.WriteLine("\nPods:");
foreach (var pod in pods.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"- {pod.Metadata.NamespaceProperty}/{pod.Metadata.Name}");
}


Yeah, but I need more deeper resources inside node pool:  nodes, pods etc.

@IndianCodeMaster for that you will need to also add the KubernetesClient I think. Let me update the answer.
